# Solving the differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I have to solve the following differential equation:
>   $$ (D+1)(D+2x)y=0 $$

My approach:
\begin{align*}
(D+1)(D+2x)y=0\implies (D+1)y=0\ \text{or}\ (D+2x)y=0\\
\implies (D+1)y=0\implies D=-1\implies y=c_1e^{-x}
\end{align*}
Now $(D+2x)y=0\implies Dy+2xy=0\implies y=c_2e^{-x^2}.$
Hence the general solution will be $$c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{-x^2}$$
Am I correct?

Comment: No I am asking about my method.

Comment: You can check it by direct substitution. It doesn't work with $e^{-x}$. Caution, the operators do not commute.

Comment: It' correct.!..

Comment: @MyGlass But I checked it now it does not satisfying the differential equation.

Comment: Differential equation?

Comment: It is $y''+(2x+1)y'+2(1+x)y=0$

Comment: I'm eager to know how did you derive $(D+1)(D+2x)y=0$ from DE!

Comment: No I haven't. The question was in the form of $D$ only, I have just opened it to get the differential equation.

Comment: Anyway, they aren't the same thing. Delete $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{-x^2}$ to obtain DE of this solution.

Comment: I'm assuming the $D$ is the differential operator?

Comment: So my solution is correct. But still I have doubt that why my differential equation is not same as the operator.

Comment: Let $Dy+2xy=g(x)$, then $g'(x)+g(x)=0$, hence $g(x)=ce^{-x}$. So, $y'(x)+2xy=ce^{-x}$. The integrating factor is $v(x)=x^{2}$, so $y(x)=ce^{-x^{2}}\int{e^{x^{2}-x}}dx$